# WinX. FULLY functional USB Flash Drive stopped working when usin a recovery tool (EaseUS). EaseUS became unresponsive, leading to the drive errors

Tags: windows-10, command-line, data-recovery, usb-flash-drive, easeus-partition-manager

USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB Device (64Gb Flash Drive) 
WinX 
EaseUS

The drive is visible in Windows Explorer but... 
 if I click to open it... 
 the cursor changes to the hourglass icon for about 40 seconds... 
 then I get this error popup:

| Error | When Error occurs |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Location is not available 2. D:\ is not accessible. 3. The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. | [Popop box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3qaJ.png) |

```
chdisk /f D: 
cannot open volume for direct access
```

I fear if I unplug it & replug it, the drive will no longer appear in windows explorer. Or that it will make the problem worse. It may also fix it, but I'm not taking that chance till I'm more aware.

## Drive is Very Precious

The drive has 63Gb of important backups on it. College, taxes, previous jobs & projects, pictures of friends and family. It's that kind of drive you put everything important on. :)
[Properties Panel of the Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJwNy.png)

## For additional clarification and context.

The flash drive WAS FULLY functional. I was only using EaseUS because I accidently deleted my Dads tax documents, I successfully recovered them, but continued playing around with the recovery tool seeing what else it could recover. And then the EaseUS window wouldn't pop up anymore, it was still visible in the taskbar but clicking the EaseUS taskbar preview did nothing and trying to close the application did nothing. I tried opening the drive from windows explorer to make sure it was okay, and that's when windows explorer froze too. After an hour of trying to close EaseUS in a subtle way, I had to `taskkill` the EaseUS `.exe`

## Questions

Since the drive was **FULLY** functional and I **HAVEN'T** unplugged the drive since the problem started occurring, what steps can I take to acquire more info about drive's status, state, and problem? What may have EaseUS done to the drive to put it in such a vulnerable state? What may have EaseUs done to the drive to cause the drive to produce an error like this upon experiencing critical problems with the EaseUS application? And just generally, how can I get the drive working again :)

Also, I have the windows setting for letting peripheral devices sleep disabled, so that's not a possible cause.

Comment: Note: Having only one copy of any data is *not* a backup, it's an accident waiting to happen - most especially on something as delicate & prone to sudden total failure as a flash drive… and even more especially, not on a FAT file system, which isn't journaled.

Comment: "What may have EaseUs done to the drive to cause the drive to produce an error […]?" – Anything, but EaseUS is not to blame. Flash drives rarely fail when being idle, they fail when being used. A tool that scans a whole drive or a tool that writes massive amount of data to a drive has more chances to "kill" the drive, only because the number of operations is high and each one may be the unlucky one. This is why Rufus or EaseUS get blamed more than Notepad, but they only do their jobs that would never kill a theoretical (i.e. eternally perfect) drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good news. I just unplugged it and replugged it back in and it worked. I was so scared unplugging it would make the problem worse but after everything I tried didn't work, it was close to the only option left.

Comment: Now will be the time to make an **actual** backup of it then ;)) Glad you got it working.